# User object is not accessable in the controller in symfony

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to use auto login feature in symfony something like firing the login event and setting the user object. The user object is available in that controller but when I try to use other controller the user object says annon instead of showing the logged in user info

**Controller A**

```
private function autoLogin($request, $username)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if (!$usr = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneBy(['username' => $username])) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('User does not exist');
    }

    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($usr, $usr->getPassword(), "secured_area", $usr->getRoles());
    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);

    $loginEvent = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
    $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $loginEvent);

    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser(); 
    dump($user); // can see user object without any issue

    if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

    return $usr;
}
```

**Controller B**

```
public function editAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser(); 
    print_r($user); // result is annon.
}
```

**security.yml**

```
security: 
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        doctrine_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        secured_area:
            anonymous: ~
            provider: doctrine_provider
            pattern: ^/

            form_login:
                login_path: security_login
                check_path: security_login
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /login

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/.*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is clear what you're trying to do. Do you log in user in a controller and then on the next page user appears to be not logged in? Or do you forward your request from one controller to another?

Comment: It would be also nice if you can provide the security.yml file as well.

Comment: @Stepashka. I have edited my question with security.yml file content. I'm trying to login in a controller and then on next page user appears not to be logged in. The object shows annon.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that you're not using any security setup and the second controller is called after user refreshes the page.

The most likely problem is that your user is not persisted into the session. `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener` is responsible for that. If you have a look at `onKernelResponse()` method you can find out how it does it. Basically it gets token from token storage, serialize it and stores to the session. On the request it does opposite: gets token from session and puts it to token storage.

I'd suggest that you play with the configuration of firewall and set up something like this:

```
firewalls:
    autologin:
        pattern: /autologinUrl/
        context: autologing
```

In this case context listener will be called doing session-related stuff and your code should work.